# Fixed position footer isn't scrollable horizontally off-screen

Tags: html, css

I need my footer to stay `fixed` to the bottom of the page at all times, and I also need to give it a `minimum-width` so that the left content and right content don't collide into each other (as per the designer's mock up).  The problem arises if the user's viewport is too skinny, the right side of the content gets cut off the screen, and there's no way to access it.  I'd really like to not have to change the way the menu behaves (adding media query breakpoints or something) and would rather have a menu that acts more like `position:absolute` but is always at the bottom a la `position:fixed`.

Any ideas?

```css
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 500px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #eee;
    height: 50px;
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
    <div class="left">my left content</div>
    <div class="right">my right content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the **min-width** property for each side as

```
.left {
    float: left;
    min-width:250px;
}

.right {
    float: right;
    min-width:250px;
}
```

You can also set them to a smaller px size to make the right side stay open at a smaller width. If you really want to be fancy you could create a media query to remove the float at a certain width